# Получить значение radiobutton

Tags: jquery

Есть две радиокнопки

```
<input type="radio" id="c1" name="cc" checked="" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>&nbsp;государственные</label>
<input type="radio" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>&nbsp;частные</label>
```

При определенном событии (при скролинге слайдера) я должен получить выбранное значение радиокнопки, как сделать это через jquery?

UPD

Кому поможет код скроллинга

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        grid:true,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        from: 1,
        to: 5,
        step: 1,
        onFinish: function (data) {
          titleSearch = $("#titleSearch").val();
          typeSearch = $("#typeSearch").val();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/searchResult',
            data : {
              'min':data.from,
              'max':data.to,
              'titleSearch':titleSearch,
              'typeSearch':typeSearch
            },
            success: function(answer) {
              $(".searchResult").slideDown(500);
            }
          });

          console.log(data.from);
          console.log(data.to);

        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: А есть код скроллинга слайдера?)

Comment: @duddeniska Можно уточнить связь первой части кода со вторым?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Получить выбранную радиокнопку довольно просто

```
$('input[name=cc]:checked')
```

Для каждой радио кнопки добавьте атрибут `value` с уникальным значением для его идентификации.

Получаем выбранное значение:

```
$('input[name=cc]:checked').val()
```